# How to set classification to delta when use Athena to register Delta table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

When use AWS Glue crawler, there is a classification `delta` in AWS Glue Catalog.

I can use Athena to register Delta table AWS Glue Catalog by

```sql
create external table hm_iot_db.motor2
location 's3://hongbomiao-bucket/delta-tables/motor/'
tblproperties (
    'table_type' = 'delta'
);
```

This will register Delta table `motor2` in the AWS Glue Catalog:

[image]

However, you can see classification is missing.

I tried to add `'classification' = 'delta'` by

```sql
create external table hm_iot_db.motor3
location 's3://hongbomiao-bucket/delta-tables/motor/'
tblproperties (
    'table_type' = 'delta',
    'classification' = 'delta'
);
```

However, after registering, `delta` is still not shown for classification.

I found the corresponding `classification` document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html

But the document only mentions about `csv`, `parquet`, `orc`, `avro`, `json`, without `delta`.

I know I can edit the table properties and add `classfication: delta` manually after I register / create the table.

Is there a way to set classification to `delta` during the registration of the table by Athena? Thanks!